# In android how can i reduce my image size from 70 kb to 30 kb programatically?

Tags: android

I am developing an app in android that will capture a photo and store in sqlite.
The image size is 70 kb but i want to store that image with 35 kb size. But i can't get any idea for this. I tried the following code but without success.

```
int photo_width = bm.getWidth();
int photo_height = bm.getHeight();

photo_width = 260;
photo_height = 260;

Bitmap photobitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm,
    photo_width, photo_height, false);
```

Comment: Compress your bitmap object..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bitmap.compress()` to produce a compressed version.

Comment: i used that... photobitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytearrayoutputsrteam);...but not working

Comment: by using 100 you are compressing using max quality.

Comment: then which value i can use?

Comment: anything between 0 - 100, 0 meaning compress for the smallest size. So you will have to pick which will work best for your image.

Comment: i want to make my image of 35 k.b. fix size